# Я хочу чтоб style.css был на github, и я его подключил

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, github

Чтоб было удобнее я хочу разместить на github style.css, но я не понимаю как его подключить

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nazar1ky/Style_css/main/style.css">
```

Comment: так же как и для локального проекта, относительно страницы на которой вы подключаете файл

Comment: У меня файл на компютере а я хочу подключить к нему стили которые на github

Comment: между head вставьте эту строчку

Comment: она у меня и так между head

Comment: а зачем такое проворачивать? Лучше и удобнее оттуда их скачать)

Comment: в чём трудности тогда ?

Comment: Ну мне нужно...

Comment: стили не работают

Comment: скриншот как вы и где их подключали, мы не гадалки

Comment: конечно не работают - github не даёт такую возможность

Comment: <head>
 <meta sharset="utf-8">
 <title>VK Token</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nazar1ky/Style_css/master/style.css">

 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shojumaru&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

Comment: хех, мне кажется нужно вместо raw поставить stylesheet, как и Максим сделал ;)

Comment: не работает - github как обычно ..не отдаёт

Comment: и что делать???

Comment: ctrl + c, ctrl + v

Comment: ладно я понял.........